Disble component PackageInstallerActivity permanently
I want to disble this component in my Android phone following these commands via ADB:
# adb root
# adb shell pm disable com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity

But when I did a factory reset, it enabled again.
I tried to delete it but it's java source code, not apk file, so, I can't delete it via this path:
frameworks/base/packages/PackageInstaller/src/com/android/packageinstaller/PackageInstallerActivity.java 
I want it to be removed permanently and can't enable back even after doing a factory reset.

Possibly you will have to create a custom android build, i still don't think it is actually possible to fully remove package installer even then. But i have not tried to make a custom android build for my devices

I can remove it permanently but only apk file

Of course a factory reset removes all modifications you did as it erased the code mplete user data partition. Making changes to the system partition requires root permissions or directly a customROM that already contains the changes you want.
